# How do I prove that $y$ can be defined as a a linear combination of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ in multiple different ways?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$  be a linearly dependent vector system in $S$ and let $y\in S$ be vector that can be defined as a linear combination of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. How do I prove that $y$ can be defined as a a linear combination of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ in multiple different ways?

Comment: well, since they are dependent, you can have an equality of the sort $x_1.a_1+...+x_n.a_n=0,$ where not all $a_i$ are 0.Then express y in $x_i$ and add $x_1.a_1+...+x_n.a_n=0.$This always works when they are dependent, there is nothing special about $Z_p.$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_1,...,x_n$ are linearly dependent there exists non-zero constants $k_1,...,k_n$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_ix_i =0$$

Now lets assume $y = \sum_{i=1}^{n} g_ix_i$ for some constants $g_1,...,g_n$ then we can state $$y =\sum_{i=1}^{n} g_ix_i +0$$
$$y =\sum_{i=1}^{n} g_ix_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n}k_ix_i$$
$$y = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(k_i + g_i)x_i$$

Since $\forall k_i \ne 0$ there exists a different combination for $y$

The arguement can then be further extended by adding any multiple of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_ix_i$ to $y$

Comment: Because if $k_i \ne 0$ then $g_i + k_i \ne g_i$ so you get a different combination